# UseStatusCodePages() position in request pipeline

Tags: asp.net-core

I have aspnet core MVC project with bearer authentication (token is received from another api).

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultForbidScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, config =>
{
    config.Authority = configuration["TokenServerUrl"];
    config.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            context.Token = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["access_token"];
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
    };
});
```

I needed redirection to Login page on unauthorized request, so I found UseStatusCodePages() method.
The weird thing is that UseStatusCodePages must be placed BEFORE the authorization middleware:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(context => 
{
    var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            
    if (response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized ||
        response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
    {
        response.Redirect("/Account/Login");
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
});
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        "default",
        "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

I thought, that UseAuthentication middleware returns 401 and then it can be handled. So how UseStatusCodePages middleware handles 401 code if it placed before UseAuthentication ? If I'll place UseStatusCodePages after UseAuthorization - it will not be called at all and it's weird. Can anybody explain this behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Middleware doesn’t run before or after another middleware; instead, middleware runs *around* or *inside* other middleware.

In your example setup, this is how the middleware executes:

```
Request
| StatusCodePages
| ⮩ (next)
    | StaticFiles
    | ⮩ (next)
        | Routing
        | ⮩ (next)
            | Authentication
            | ⮩ (next)
                | Authorization
                | ⮩ (next)
                    | Endpoints
                    | (serve request)
                    | ⮨
                | ⮨
            | ⮨
        | ⮨
    | ⮨
| ⮨
```

Each middleware has the chance to do some work, and then it calls the *next* middleware in the pipeline. Once that next middleware has completed, the middleware gets another chance to do some handling after the inner middlewares are done.

In the case of the StatusCodePages middleware, what it does is execute the next middleware, and once that completes, it looks at the resulting status code and runs your custom handler which has the chance to modify the response.

If you swapped the order around, then the StatusCodePages middleware would run *inside* the middlewares that produces the 401/403 status codes and as such wouldn’t be able to act on their result.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it's a pipeline, but in real it's a callstack